# code igniter cms that can run multiple websites like site1.com site2.com?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a `CodeIgniter` CMS out there that supports running multiple websites from one codebase?

I would like to point my dns to `site1.com` , `site2.com` and then the CMS should serve the right website.

Already searched for CI projects with this functionality but nothing much came up, anyone has a recommendation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had a solution for this. I checked the domain you came from, and was using different configuration file for this in which I pointed to different url.php (sorry I'm not in php for 2 years so I hardly remember filenames). This was all done in that main codeigniter php file before anything else is initialiased.

Comment: p.s. as far as I remember codeigniter handles lot's of stuff with htaccess.. so it's possible that if you using mod_rewrite for CI, you need to define global variable in htaccess which write current domain from which user came from.. and then you can easily get it with php in $_GLOBAL i think.. =) hope this helped

Answer (score 3):

I believe the professional version of `PyroCMS` can do this, it's not free though. Have a look:

[Pyro CMS](http://www.pyrocms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on [how to do this](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/How-to-Multi-site-CodeIgniter-Set-up) back in 2009 and the code still stands:

The implementation in PyroCMS is better, and for $90 it's a lot of trouble taken off your hands.